# Rails 4 exception from CoffeeScript: ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I have ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken when trying to submit dynamically created form from coffeescript.

I tried to pass authenticity_token in my form request, but had no success. Can you please help me?

My CoffeeDcript code;

```
    upload_form = $('<form>', {
      'action': '/save_orders',
      'method': 'post'
    }).append($('<input>', {
      'data': my_json
    }));
    upload_form.submit();
```

Please note, that i neeed to create and submit form dynamically, so i can't prepare it on html page and then reuse in js. Also it should be form request (not ajax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere in a rails view (e.g. application.html.erb file) you can set a global js variable like this:

```
window._token = '<%= form_authenticity_token %>';
```

Then when create a form you can append it to the form like this:

```
upload_form = $('<form>', {
  'action': '/save_orders',
  'method': 'post'
}).append($('<input>', {
  'data': my_json
})).append($('<input>', {
  'type': 'hidden',
  'name': 'authenticity_token',
  'value': window._token
}));
upload_form.submit();
```